Modify section name in pdf navigation menu
I'm using hyperref to create a navigation menu in my article. The problem is that my subsection titles contain various mathematical fonts (like \mathbb and \mathcal) which don't render in the navigation menu.
How can I manually change their names in the menu to correct for this (without changing the names of the subsections themselves)?

@JoséCarlosSantos I don't think so (unless I'm misinterpeting it). The error message is fine; the issue is the actual bookmark in the pdf viewer.

use \texorpdfstring{$\mathcal{C}$}{C}

If by ``navigation'' menu you mean a table of contents or the bookmarks in the pdf viewer then:

\section[Something about C]{Something about \mathcal{C}}

should solve it

this would change the representation in the table of contents too.
